# How intialize rabbitmq via masstransit?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, masstransit

I try to implement rabbitmq via masstransit as in instruction https://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/rabbitmq.html#cloudamqp

But Bus (IBusControl) doesn't have Factory method.

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq
```

MassTransit, MassTransit.RabbitMQ - 6.2.0 version.

Do you know what I forgot include?

Comment: Look at any sample repository, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a conflict with a method called Bus and static class Bus.
Should use namespace path

```
MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq
```